# Trying to install landscape server. Agent stuck on: Waiting for agent initialization to finish

Tags: juju, landscape

I am running Juju on Trusty and attempting to install Landscape dense MAAS.

Juju status shows as:

```
Waiting for agent initialization to finish
```

I logged into the machine itself. The logs for: haproxy, postgres, etc. show the same error.

It seems it's trying to acquire KVM when it's using LXC as containers.

```
2016-03-06 15:37:18 DEBUG juju.worker.proxyupdater proxyupdater.go:151 new proxy settings proxy.Settings{Http:"", Https:"", Ftp:"", NoProxy:"localhost,xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"}

2016-03-06 15:37:18 DEBUG juju.network network.go:268 no lxc bridge addresses to filter for machine

2016-03-06 15:37:18 INFO juju.worker.machiner machiner.go:132 setting addresses for machine-0-lxc-2 to ["local-machine:127.0.0.1" "local-cloud:xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" "local-machine:::1"]
2016-03-06 15:37:18 DEBUG juju.worker.logger logger.go:45 reconfiguring logging from "<root>=DEBUG" to "<root>=WARNING;unit=DEBUG"

2016-03-06 15:37:19 WARNING juju.cmd.jujud machine.go:948 determining kvm support: INFO: /dev/kvm does not exist
HINT:   sudo modprobe kvm_intel
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod.c:556 kmod_search_moddep() could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.13.0-79-generic/modules.dep.bin'
: exit status 1
no kvm containers possible
```

Comment: Please include juju status output and the contents of /var/log/juju on the bootstrap node. The kvm message is misleading and not an error.

Comment: I figured it out... lxc was trying to resolve the hostname that was given by maas. So the containers where trying to connect to the boostrap node using xxxxxxx.maas I need to talk to the networking guys to fix the dns resolving of maas names. But for now I modified the lxc container hosts file. Seems to have done the trick.